# Shopify, formatMoney use current currency dynamically

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am using [this](https://gist.github.com/stewartknapman/8d8733ea58d2314c373e94114472d44c) script for formatting money in Shopify. The problem is that I'd need the flexibility of having multiple currencies and the current function doesn't seem to support it.

I've tried including that script in a `.liquid` file, and using `{{ currency.symbol }}` like: `Shopify.money_format = "{{ currency.symbol }}" + "{{amount}}";` or `"{{ currency.symbol }}{{amount}}";` or `{{ currency.symbol }} + "{{amount}}";` but that gives an error with `placeholderRegex` which becomes undefined.

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is the code where I use the function:

```
Shopify.onItemAdded = function(line_item) {
    jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
       // change total price
       $('#popup_total').html(Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price))
    });
};
```

EDIT[2]: At the end I went with a different approach. I declared the current currency variable outside the function, and then I replace the original $ symbol, with whatever currency symbol the store has. It goes like this:

```
var currentCurrency = '{{ cart.currency.symbol }}'

Shopify.onItemAdded = function(line_item) {
    jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
         var total = Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price).replace('$', currentCurrency)
         $('#popup_total').html(total)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That function doesn't limit you to a single currency - the first parameter is the unformatted amount, and the second is the desired format, which can have whichever currency you want - e.g. `"€ {{amount}}"`

EDIT:

It looks like you aren't using the second format parameter.  Could you try:

```
Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price, "€{{amount}}")
```

Or whatever currency you want there?  Thanks for providing additional code, but it's still difficult to understand the input and desired output, as well as other variables you have access to (you mentioned a dynamic currency, but where is that stored? Which variable?)

Comment: But when I change the store's currency, it won't change the price's currency which I'm injecting with this script. So I want the currency symbol to be displayed dynamically relative to the store's current currency. Maybe I didn't understand your answer?

Comment: That function you are using is intended for multiple currencies, so you should be able to reuse it as is - thats all I was suggesting.   I suspect there should be a way to utilize that with your setup.  That being said, its difficult to provide additional guidance without seeing any of the code you are referencing, so you might want to update your question with more of your code

Comment: I added the code where I use the function. The amount itself changes when changing the currency, just the symbol doesn't. But if I change  `"${{amount}}"` in `"€{{amount}}"` then it will display `€` like you said. Can't I just include some liquid inside the function like I tried?

Comment: Updated with a bit more, but could still use a bit more clarity on the available inputs and desired output

Answer (score 0):

default for Dollar

```
Shopify.formatMoney(data.price)
```

For Pound sterling money format

```
Shopify.formatMoney(data.price, "£{{amount}}")
```

For Euro money format

```
Shopify.formatMoney(data.price, "€{{amount}}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try that

```
let currencySymbol = {{ cart.currency.symbol }}
```

and replace with

```
Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price).replace('$', 'currencySymbol');
```